# Terminal Logo gets misplaced after changing the theme

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-terminal, logo

Recently I changed my Ubuntu 18.04 theme to MacOS theme. No sooner I installed the theme, I found the misplaced terminal icon in terminal window. I tried uninstalling and re-installing the terminal, wandered in terminal preferences, but came with no result.

I need to know how the misplaced terminal logo can be removed or placed rightly.

This is how it looks like:
[image: This is how it looks like :]